# В чем проблема с форматированием HTML текста в textView

Tags: java, android, html, kotlin, форматирование

Добрый день Вроде мелкая проблема,но совсем не могу понять. Есть условная строка содержащая HTML текст :

```
 "text_html": "<p><strong>При покупке от 2500 рублей начисляется повышенный Бонус - 15% на 
 всю сумму в чеке.</strong></p>\r\n<p><strong>1 Бонус = 1 Рубль.</strong><strong><br 
 />Телефон +7 (999) 999-999.</strong></p>\r\n<h6>*Акция не распространяется на табак и 
 табачные изделия; на товары-участники ценовых акций. В случае пересечения акционных 
 предложений - начисляется максимальный Бонус. Организатор акции оставляет за собой право 
 изменить условия или досрочно прекратить акцию.</h6>"
```

Если взять эту строку и посмотреть через браузер будет выглядеть вот так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст в теге h6 выглядит мельче прочего. Все верно. Но если эту же самую строку вставить в textView:

```
   description.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(partner.getText_html(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

Разницы по размеру текста нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем, если бы вместо тега h6 был бы например h5, то содержимое тега визуально выглядело больше прочего текста. Может кто-то просветить почему?